# Question on Fuse Placing

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electronics

Please answer Q.no 11 (where should the fuse be placed and why?)

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

A few points that might help you to answer the question *yourself*:

1. The *basic function of a fuse* is to **stop the flow of electric current** above a specified limit *to avoid overheating of electrical equipments and their subsequent damage*.
2. The fuse works by breaking the electric circuit when the current in the circuit suddenly increases to a very high value. The current causes *melting of the fuse material* and this breaks the circuit.
3. Keeping all this in mind, the fuse must be placed in such a way that *if the current in the circuit suddenly increases to a very high value, the fuse melts and breaks the circuit, before the electrical equipments are damaged*.
4. So, in a parallel connection, to prevent damage of all the equipments at the same time, *the fuse must be placed in the main circuit, rather then in the branches*.

The answer is clearly evident from the last $2$ hints and the first $2$ hints substantiate the explanation. Hope this helps you.

Comment: @ Schrodingers Cat, It means the fuse should be placed at A?

Comment: Whatever you think; my hints are almost self-sufficient. The rest is for you to decide.